# Simulating numeric keyboard in TestComplete

Tags: keyboard-events, testcomplete

is there a way to simulate numeric keyboard in TestComplete? I know I can type  [NumMinus] to use Num -, but I need numbers from this keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use the format `[Xnn]`

Specifies a key by its virtual-key code. nn is the decimal virtual-key code of the desired key. For example, `[X107]` corresponds to the Num Plus key. To learn more about virtual-key codes, see the Virtual-Key Codes article in the MSDN library. The on-line version of the article is available at http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645540.aspx.

Original source - http://www.automatedqa.com/support/viewarticle/12182/